# 514 Authentication required when using Tor

Tags: 11.04, proxy, tor

I have installed Vidalia and when I activate Tor and set the proxies in firefox I get the message '514 Authentication Required.'!
I'm wondering what is the problem here?

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using,? have you configured Vidalia and Tor? https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en

Comment: I'm using 11.04 and I installed Vidalia through the Software Center and yes, I have configured it.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at this question, it might solve your problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/92922/tor-check-failed-though-vidalia-shows-green-onion

Comment: If you are using firefox, you might not require setting the proxies through the system-wide Network settings, but I have not tried with that setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this message comes when you entered a wrong port. Please check that you chose port *9050* in your Firefox settings. The 514 error code comes when you choose 9051. This port is called control port and works only with some form of authentication. However a better alternative is to use Polipo or Privoxy. If you also install them you have to choose port 8123 for Polipo and 8118 for Privoxy. After entering those data you should visit the [check page](http://check.torproject.org/). It will tell you if you are using Tor or not.

Comment: I've explained how to setup a password at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33726166/895245